# Loading bundled file from different repository in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sails.js, bower

I have a large app with many React.js components, so I decided to split them into standalone repositories. Every component have following structure:

```
build
  bundle.js - Bundled src (via Webpack or Browserify)
src
  ... - Source files
```

Then I just install this component via NPM or Bower to my application written in Sails.js

The problem comes when I need load this component from browser. My first idea was to allow access to `node_modules` from browser, but I'm not sure if it's good idea.

My second idea was to create every component as git submodule in my main application, but I have no experience with it.

Do you have any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at browserify!

Comment: I'm using browserify equivalent. I just need to load bundled file from another repository in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) to bundle up dependencies in `node_modules` into a single JS file usable in the browser.